# Issue with Xcode Server: No services available

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode-server

I'm trying to run a Xcode server with remote access.

I've been trying to log in from a client/node PC, with no success. There's a message with the IP and a warning "No services unavailable".

Is there something I'm missing here?

Screenshot is attached.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of IP address is 65.60.192.130? Is that the address of the server on the open internet or the address of a broadband router? if it is a broadband router, you will need to setup port forwarding on it to forward the server connection to the actual server doing the hosting. I'm guess this is the case because that IP reverse resolves to an ISP company called wideopenwest.com.

Answer (score 4):

Since from attached picture everything is running perfectly locally, I'm almost sure that the problem is in your router. So on router in port forwarding you have to open:

```
For Xcode Integration the only ports needed are 20300,20343-20345
For Website 80,443
```

And you have to make sure that you're have global IP address